# How to Transfer XML file (entered in TextArea) from one application to another in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, httpwebrequest

I have one application named ABC and other Application named XYZ.

User clicks on a button in XYZ that send Authentication XML to ABC , where ABC authenticates the received XML and sends a response XML containing URL.

After receiving URL (which is of ABC) , user enters an XML in TextArea and click on a button which should redirect User back to XYZ along with the textarea xml.

Now, Application XYZ should process the newly received xml and display a page within its application.(User should be redirected from ABC to XYZ , and never come back)

Any one has idea on how to achieve this?

I have tried below code.

```
    public void PostXMlData()
    {
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        postData = AppendUrlEncoded(postData, "myXml", taXML.Value);
        postData = AppendUrlEncoded(postData, "url", txtUrl.Text);

        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] postBytes = ascii.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

        // set up request object
        HttpWebRequest request;
        try
        {
            request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(txtUrl.Text);
        }
        catch (UriFormatException)
        {
            request = null;
        }
        if (request == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("Invalid URL: " + txtUrl.Text);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";

        // add post data to request
        Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        postStream.Flush();
        postStream.Close();

    }

    public static StringBuilder AppendUrlEncoded(StringBuilder sb, string name, string value)
    {
        if (sb.Length != 0)
            sb.Append("&");
        sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name));
        sb.Append("=");
        sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value));

        return sb;

    }
```

Comment: `I have one application named ABC and other Application named XYZ` What kind of applications are these? Console, desktop, service, Asp.net? how are they hosted? Are the URLs public? so much info is missing that would help address your issue

Comment: Applications are ASP.NET Web Application and they are IIS hosted. 
Sorry, if i am unable to clear your question , as i am new to coding

Comment: Is it MVC? is it API? is there a controller?

Comment: NO API, XYZ is an MVC application having controller ,view, etc, and ABC is just normal Web Application having Page_load and Button Click events.

Comment: Cool, so you should solve this in javascript. Essentially `Now, Application XYZ should process the newly received xml and display a page within its application` to do that, add CORS headers in XYZ and make your browser make a POST to `XYZ` with the xml, then in response have javascript use `window.location=` to redirect to `a page within its application`.