# response.AppendHeader() replacement for .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have used `response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");` inside a `OnResultExecuting()` method of a class that derives `ActionFilterAttribute`. But it returns an error like:

```
//HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
HttpResponse response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
```

> 'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'AppendHeader' and no accessible extension method 'AppendHeader' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Adding a header to a response is similar to header to a request. 
See following posting for code to add headers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71126747/how-to-transfer-xml-file-entered-in-textarea-from-one-application-to-another-i?force_isolation=true ad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The ASP.NET Core response headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iheaderdictionary?view=aspnetcore-6.0) use properties to represent most of the common headers.

To set the content encoding in .NET 6, use:

```
response.Headers.ContentEncoding = "gzip";
```

For earlier versions, you'll need to use [the `Append` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.headerdictionaryextensions.append):

```
response.Headers.Append("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
```

Comment: Tried this. but it is showing `'IHeaderDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'ContentEncoding' and no accessible extension method 'ContentEncoding' accepting a first argument of type 'IHeaderDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Looks like that property was added in .NET 6 - which version are you using?

Comment: I need the same equivalent in .NET Core 3.1

Comment: @Lim As per my updated answer, the `response.Headers.Append` extension method should work - it was defined as far back as .NET Core v1.